# How to use Action Sheet in objective c using xcode 7?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

`UIActionSheet` is showing it's deprecated in Xcode 7, how can I address this problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Cancel button tappped do nothing.

}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // take photo button tapped.
    [self takePhoto];

}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // choose photo button tapped.
    [self choosePhoto];

}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Distructive button tapped.
    [self deletePhoto];

}]];
```

You can use this code in place of `UIActionsheet` :)

You have to use `UIAlertController` with preferredStyle is `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` because `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS8 and this is iOS version issue not Xcode version issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UIAlertController` with `preferredStyle` `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` because `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS8 and this is an iOS version issue not Xcode version issue.

Comment: @GhanshyamTomar hey thanks for your suggestion, but description is also helpful for him to understand the problem..